# Equation solution

Tags: algebra-precalculus, word-problem

A zoo has few numbers of penguins and polar bears. The total number of heads of both of them is $60$ and the total number of their feet is $160$. How many polar bears are there in the zoo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x$ denote penguins and $y$ denote bears

$$x+y=60$$
$$2x+4y=160$$

Solving for $x$ and $y$ we get $$x=40,y=20$$

So, there are $40$ penguins and $20$ bears.